# Exploiting LFI with prefix in PHP?

Tags: web-application, php, exploit, vulnerability, lfi

I have a scenario as the following:

```
<?php  include("resource/" + $_GET['vuln']); ?>
```

And I'm trying to get RCE from this, or atleast acquire some interesting information.

I already looked at `/etc/passwd` and other important files. Are there things I can do to bypass the  `resource/` prefix (since it disables me from using `php://` filters)?

Comment: I am 95% sure you can't do anything about the prefix. So I think you can only include files actually found in the `resource` dir.

Comment: I assume traversals are blocked? ../../../../../etc/passwd

Comment: Actually, traversals aren't blocked. But I think I've come up with a way to get RCE: We can actually send an error request to the server, then the logfile will contain our error. BUT what if we use <?php echo $_GET['vuln']; ?> inside the error. so that when you include it, the server will parse whatever's in $_GET['vuln']

Comment: @Guysudai1 that would be the standard way to escalate this. Other potential files with PHP code to include might be `/proc/self/environ` or any file you can upload (type doesn't matter, might be image files, etc).

Comment: yea I took inspiration from that way of exploitation. Because I could not access /proc/self/environ